# Dividir una lista en arrays iguales

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, json, jsonarray

Estoy descargando datos recibidos de un JSON mediante un bucle for. Este JSON contiene varios objetos y entre ellos se encuentran el nombre `['name']` y el nombre de usuario `['username']`. Este es el JSON (una de las 9 personas que aparecen dentro):

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
  }
```

He almacenado ambas en una misma lista y esta lista sale de la siguiente manera:

```
['Leanne Graham', 'Bret', 'Ervin Howell', 'Antonette', 'Clementine Bauch', 'Samantha', 'Patricia Lebsack', 'Karianne', 'Chelsey Dietrich', 'Kamren', 'Mrs. Dennis Schulist', 'Leopoldo_Corkery', 'Kurtis Weissnat', 'Elwyn.Skiles', 'Nicholas Runolfsdottir V', 'Maxime_Nienow', 'Glenna Reichert', 'Delphine', 'Clementina DuBuque', 'Moriah.Stanton']
```

Esta lista tiene el nombre en la primear posición y el nombre de usuario en la segunda y estan todos los nombres del json. Esto lo he logrado de la siguiente manera:

```
listaNombresYUsuarios = []
for i in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]:
    data = json.loads(text)
    user = data[i]
    nombre = user['name'] 
    username = user['username']
    email = user['email']
    address = user['address']['zipcode']
    listaNombresYUsuarios.extend([nombre, username])
print(listaNombresYUsuarios)
```

Mi problema es que ahora quiero separar esta lista en arrays individuales que solo contengan el nombre y el nombre de usuario de una persona, algo así:

```
['Leanne Graham', 'Bret']
```

Para ello he escrito el siguiente código, pero no me está saliendo bien:

```
listaNombresYUsuarios = []
for i in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]:
    data = json.loads(text)
    user = data[i]
    nombre = user['name'] 
    username = user['username']
    email = user['email']
    address = user['address']['zipcode']
    listaNombresYUsuarios.extend([nombre, username])

    splits = np.array_split(listaNombresYUsuarios, 2)
    for array in splits:
        print(array)
print(listaNombresYUsuarios)
```

Además de esto, como podría hacer para en el bucle for no escribir manualmente `in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` ya que a veces el JSON varía y necesito leer más nombres?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: `for i in range(10):`

Comment: Para evitarte ese problema y ya tener los nombres separados deberías agregar una lista o una tupla dentro de la lista que ya tienes, en vez de usar `extend`. Puedes hacerlo así: `listaNombresYUsuarios.append((nombre, username))` y con eso ya tendrás lo que quieres.

Comment: @CandidMoe si esa opción la he barajado, pero a lo que me refiero es que a veces puede ser de 15 y otras de 10. Por lo que si pongo range(10) y vienen 15 nombre me faltan 5 y si  vienen 10 nombre pero tengo pueto range(10) me salta un error de que las longitudes de los index no coinciden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero carga el archiv JSON y luego procesa el contenido. Asumo que la carga de `text` ya la tiene resuelta y que lo que hay dentro del JSON es un array de objetos users. Puede cambiar un poco lo que quiere hacer y probar esto:

```
import json

# Acá debe colocar el código para abrir "text"

users = json.loads(text)

names_and_usernames = []
lista_nombres_y_usuarios = []

for user in users:
  nombre = user['name'] 
  username = user['username']
  email = user['email']
  address = user['address']['zipcode']
  lista_nombres_y_usuarios.extend([nombre, username])
  names_and_usernames.append([nombre, username])
```

Es muy posible que deba adapatar código para que se ajuste a lo que necesite.
Por cierto y aunque no viene a la pregunta, en python se escriben las variables con lower_camel_case, dele una mirada a PEP8

Comment: Gracias @omar_angarita